# Python3: Bounds for integer annotations

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I'm reading Fluent Python, and I saw an annotation style (p.154) that I'd never seen before: a bound on an integer:

```
def clip(text: str, max_len:'int>0'=80) -> str
```

Replicating that in my editor leads to a Pyright error that > is not supported for int and literal 0. Fluent python is of course clear checking annotations are for IDEs/linters to support so perhaps it isn't recognized by Pyright -- is this an annotation style that is still in use?

Comment: I've never seen such a thing before, but assuming you require `max_len` to be greater than zero, wouldn't it be a better solution to put an assertion at the beginning of the function? Or even in the docstring? It's more explicit and actual error checking is performed

Comment: Well if it was actually supported in any way by an ide/linter (although I suspect that would be impossible to do at write time), it would be super cool! But to your point it’s useless and using an actual test would be much more useful.